# Why my JavaScript function is executing uncertainly if i add an alert()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, getjson

I wrote the function below to get the length of a `listbox` with the id `courselessons`. The problem is that when I comment the `alert()` the function `changecheckbox` works only once.

If I remove the `alert` it works fine. But I don't want to have an alert on every single click.

The `selOpts` shows correct content only for the first time.

#### JavaScript:

```
function changecheckbox() {
   //alert("function called...");
   var selOpts = document.getElementById("courselessons").length();
   alert(selOpts);
   if (selOpts > 0) {
       $('#taskassignment').prop('disabled', false);
   }
   else {
       $('#taskassignment').prop('disabled', true).prop("checked", false);
   }
}

function addItem() {
   if (seltask == undefined || seltask.length === 0) {
       return;
   }
   var lessonsDropdown = $('#courselessons');
   lessonsDropdown.empty();
   $("#tasks option:selected").appendTo("#coursetasks");
   $("#coursetasks option").attr("selected", false);
   if (seltask.length > 0) {
       cacheToken = new Date().getTime();
       // retrieve data using a Url.Action() to construct url
       $.getJSON('@Url.Action("AddTaskToCourse")', {
           task: seltask,
           lesson: lesson,
           _: cacheToken
       });
       $.getJSON('@Url.Action("UpdateLessonInCourse")', {
           _: cacheToken
       }).done(function (data) {
           //re-enable tasks drop down
           //for each returned tasks
           $.each(data, function (i, lessons) {
               //Create new option
               var test = $('<option />').html(lessons);
               //append tasks taskss drop down
               lessonsDropdown.append(test);
           });
           seltask = null;
       });
    }
    changecheckbox();
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="btnAdd" onclick="addItem(); changecheckbox();">Add Item</button>
```

Comment: It is important to see how you are executing this function, can you show that code please?

Comment: Please add your HTML.

Comment: What is `addItem` doing?

Comment: It appears your `addItem()` is doing something the way you don't anticipate, just a guess for now.

Comment: addItem() --> Adds the items from one listbox to another

Comment: is adfItem() completed before the changecheckbox() is triggered?

Comment: Now i can suspect what is going on, both of your functions are executing on same handler and it is possible that there is some race condition going on there.

Comment: yeah it should. I could add the function call for "changecheckbox()" at the end of the "addItem()" function. Could that work?

Comment: Yes. If you add `changecheckbox()` as a callback function to `addItem()` then it would be even better.

Comment: The second time when I click the button and fire the function it doesn't work too, even if there are items in the list.

Comment: Now it is a good time if you could revise your post with everything that is missing and you have done so far. Otherwise it would be so unclear to everyone.

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous. Can't call `changecheckbox()` until the updates are done in the `$.getJSON` callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code inside `addItem()` is making a `GET` request to a resource `asynchronously`. This means the code which comes after this function to be execute will not wait for its execution to get complete.

> When I uncomment the alert it works fine.

That is because as the `alert()` is built in, it halts the execution of script until user interaction. This gave the time `addItem()` needs and everything seems to work.

Fortunately, there are solutions available to handle this situation.

1. [Promise.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
2. Rearrange your code to work with callbacks.

Under the covers, `$.getJSON` is shorthand for making a `GET` request using `ajax` with `datatype = 'json'`and it returns a promise object which basically tells that please wait honey, i will give you something which could be a success or a failure but sometime later.

So yes, you can easily call the function inside the `done()`.

NOTE: These things have been explained pretty well on web so i will not reinvent the wheel :)

Keeping the things simple...

```
function addItem() {

    // Rest of the code...

    if (seltask.length > 0) {
        cacheToken = new Date().getTime();
        // retrieve data using a Url.Action() to construct url
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("AddTaskToCourse")', {
            task: seltask,
            lesson: lesson,
            _: cacheToken
        });
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("UpdateLessonInCourse")', {
            _: cacheToken
        }).done(function (data) {
            //re-enable tasks drop down
            //for each returned tasks
            $.each(data, function (i, lessons) {
                //Create new option
                var test = $('<option />').html(lessons);
                //append tasks taskss drop down
                lessonsDropdown.append(test);
            });
            seltask = null;
            changecheckbox();
        });

    }        
}
```

After this setup, you should remove the `changecheckbox()` call from the button `onclick` otherwise it would make it execute twice.

Comment: Perfect thank you that's amazing. Now it runs perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Try using like this,

```
function changecheckbox() {
    //alert("function called...");
    var selOpts = $("courselessons").find('option').length;

    if (selOpts > 0) {
        $('#taskassignment').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
        $('#taskassignment').prop({'disabled':true, 'checked':false});
    }
}
```

or you can do like this ,

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

 var selOpts = $("#courselessons").find('option').length;

    if (selOpts > 0) {
        $('#taskassignment').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
        $('#taskassignment').prop({'disabled':true, 'checked':false});
    }

});
```

Comment: typo here - should be:var selOpts = $("#courselessons").find('option').length;

Comment: can also chain the jquery:        $('#taskassignment').prop('disabled', true).prop("checked", false);

Comment: @gavgrif, we can add multiple property in one method. Like this 

$(selector).prop({property:value, property:value,...})

Comment: yeah you are right gavgrif. Thank you! I changed the jquery to your suggestion.

Comment: And Samir that doesn't work :( no idea why. The same problem as before. It doesn't fire the second time.

Comment: I have writen another method, Please try using like that.

Comment: Same problem :( it's not a problem of the javscript function it's a probelm with the second call of the function.

Comment: In that case, try to merge both the function, in one. Hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the options, and take the id of select `<select id="mySelect">`  example:

```
var selOpts = document.getElementById("mySelect").length;
```

and your code will be

```
function changecheckbox() {
        //alert("function called...");
        var selOpts = document.getElementById("courselessons").length;
        if (selOpts > 0) {
            $('#taskassignment').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else {
            $('#taskassignment').prop('disabled', true);
            $("#taskassignment").prop("checked", false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Every solution in that post work, but only with the alert before.

Comment: the reason why the including the alert works is that it provides a delay in which the second function can be triggered instead of doing it at once - in efect it is a timeout function )